# Why does Python perform an `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl call when opening a character device file?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop, ioctl

I'm currently developing a Linux device driver and am currently putting the whole character device infrastructure business in place; mostly boring stuff, populate `file_operations` structure with handler functions and in parallel I'm writing a small test suite in Python.

Relevant code kernel side (not much to see here really)

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 32)
/* We try to keep the preprocessor #if/#endif mayhem to a minimum, but
 * this is one of the few places where there's no way around it, other
 * than obfuscating the function definitions behind proprocessor mayhem
 * at a different place.
 *
 * The following two helper macros abstract away the kernel version specific
 * ioctl function prototypes and access to the file pointer inode. */

#define IOCTL_FUNC(name, _inode, _filp, _cmd, _args) \
    int name(struct inode *_inode, struct file  *_filp, unsigned int _cmd, unsigned long _args)
#define IOCTL_INODE(_filp, _inode) \
    (void)_inode;
#else
#define IOCTL_FUNC(name, _inode, _filp, _cmd, _args) \
    long name(struct file  *_filp, unsigned int _cmd, unsigned long _args)
#  define IOCTL_INODE(_filp, _inode) \
    struct inode *_inode = file_inode(_filp); \
    (void)_inode;
#endif

static
int dwdsys_dev_from_inode_or_file(
    struct inode *inode,
    struct file *filp,
    struct dwddev **out_dwd )
{
    int rc = -ENODEV;
    struct dwddev *dwd = NULL;
    struct dwdsys_linux *dsl;
    list_for_each_entry( dsl, &dwdsys_list, entry ){
        if( MAJOR(asl->devno_base) == MAJOR(inode->i_rdev) ){
            unsigned const i_board = MINOR(inode->i_rdev);
            if( i_board < dsl->ds.n_boards ){
                dwd = dsl->ds.board[i_board];
                rc= 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* XXX: cache dwd in either filp->private_data or inode->i_private */
    if( !rc ){
        if( out_dwd ){ *out_dwd = dwd; }
    }
    return rc;
}

static IOCTL_FUNC(dwdsys_chrdev_ioctl, inode, filp, cmd, args)
{
    int rc;
    struct dwddev *dwd= NULL;
    IOCTL_INODE(filp, inode);

    rc= dwdsys_dev_from_inode_or_file(inode, filp, &dwd);
    if( rc ){ goto fail; }
    switch( cmd ){
    default:
        rc= -EINVAL;
        break;

    case ...:
        /* ... */
    }

fail:
    DWD__TRACE_FUNCTION(dwd, rc, "cmd=0x%08x, args=%p", cmd, (void*)args); 
    return rc;
}

static struct file_operations dwdsys_chrdev_fops = {
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 30)
    .ioctl          = dwdsys_chrdev_ioctl,
#else
    .unlocked_ioctl = dwdsys_chrdev_ioctl,
#endif
};
```

And I just noticed that when I open the driver's device node within the Python interactive REPL the driver will report an unsupported ioctl call, command code 0x5413 which translates into `TIOCSWINSZ`. That would be ioctl that's being used on VTs/PTYs to set the window size. I can see why the Python REPL would do that ioctl on, say, stdio. But it seems an odd thing to do unconditionally.

Here's what I do in the Python REPL

```
>>> dwd = open("/dev/dwd0a", "r")
```

That's it. This will make my driver spit a warning into the kernel log, that an unsupported ioctl was called.

So the question is: Is this intended, specified behaviour? Or is this something unintended, they maybe should be reported as a bug?

#### Update due to request in comments / console output of strace-ed session

```
dw@void: ~/dwd/src/linux master ⚡
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 19 2016, 17:19:49) 
[GCC 4.9.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dwd = open("/dev/dwd0a", "r")
[1]  + 1906 suspended  python
```

At this point, **before hitting enter** I suspended the Python REPL process, and attached strace to it, before foregrounding it again…

```
dw@void: ~/dwd/src/linux master ⚡
$ sudo strace -p 1906 &
[2] 1922
strace: Process 1906 attached                                                                                      
--- stopped by SIGTSTP ---
 
dw@void: ~/dwd/src/linux master ⚡
$ fg
[1]  - 1906 continued  python
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=738, si_uid=1000} ---
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [0])
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7fd1524463e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd152fbcbef}, {0x7fd152668980, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd152fbcbef}, 8) = 0
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
writev(1, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2) = 1
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7fd152668980, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd152fbcbef}, {0x7fd1524463e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fd152fbcbef}, 8) = 0
open("/dev/dwd0a", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(240, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7fffb1291f00)    = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Invalid seek)
ioctl(3, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7fffb1291eb0)    = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
getcwd("/home/dw/dwd/src/linux", 1024) = 31
stat("/home/dw/dwd/src/linux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.5", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.5/_bootlocale.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1301, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/python3.5/_bootlocale.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1301, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1028, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1028, ...}) = 0
read(4, "\26\r\r\n5\253\7X\25\5\0\0\343\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\0\0\0@\0\0"..., 1029) = 1028
read(4, "", 1)                          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Invalid seek)
brk(0x562c9d5c0000)                     = 0x562c9d5c0000
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=45, ws_col=115, ws_xpixel=809, ws_ypixel=589}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=45, ws_col=115, ws_xpixel=809, ws_ypixel=589}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=45, ws_col=115, ws_xpixel=809, ws_ypixel=589}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=45, ws_col=115, ws_xpixel=809, ws_ypixel=589}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
writev(1, [{iov_base=">>> ", iov_len=4}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2>>> ) = 4
```

Comment: can you run `strace -f` on the python process and show the output when you run `dwd = open("/dev/dwd0a", "r")`  ? Maybe it'll give us some more hints.

Comment: @nos: Added an strace, but it's not telling anything more, than what we knew already. Python opens the file and immediately starts ioctl-ing it, without being asked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've some similar problems when calling an ioctl of a (custom) linux driver. I found out that using [os.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) solves my problem. In the description of os.open they say that it is intended for low-level I/O. So maybe you shouldn't open device nodes with build-in open() even if everybody does it? If it wouldn't be a custom driver with an error message about unknown ioctls I would have never recognised that there are some other ioctls anyway.

**Using built-in open():**

```
with open('/dev/hdmi_0_0_0', 'r') as fd:
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, 0x40084814, reg_acc)
```

=>

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/hdmi_0_0_0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(239, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0xffe55e68)            = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffe55d58, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0xffe55e08)            = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
_llseek(3, 0, 0xffe55c48, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_READ, 0x48, 0x14, 0x8), 0xffe55c38) = 0
```

**Using os.open():**

```
fd = os.open('/dev/hdmi_0_0_0', os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
fcntl.ioctl(fd, 0x40084814, reg_acc)
os.close(fd)
```

=>

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/hdmi_0_0_0", O_RDWR|O_SYNC|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
ioctl(3, _IOC(_IOC_READ, 0x48, 0x14, 0x8), 0xffa076e8) = 0
```